# project/ insert an element into a material component (pagination)

Tags: angular, angular-material

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itww5x-iu9kzp)

- where I tried a couple of things already
- I was yet not able to get the nativeElement of the pagination.

Im trying to get this here

- `position: absolute` is not an option because the position of the pagination is not static

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: i have done this in past and i will post code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itww5x-oxmvt2?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.html

I have made it in the left corner

css

```
.addBtn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

.example-container {
   position: relative;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table></mat-table>
    <mat-paginator></mat-paginator>
    <button class="addBtn" mat-raised-button color="primary" >Add Role</button>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution works but a think that is CSS related: I dont understand why `.addBtn {
    position: absolute; }` is not absolute to the whole window but only to `.example-container`.

Comment: because the `position: relative` in parent makes the `absolute` child limit into it

Comment: thanks thats what I intuitivly expected. Thanks you helped me sir!